# How to make hibernate print generate SQL statements only once?

Tags: hibernate

I have hibernate configured to print out the sql statements that it generates and i have a background task that runs every 10 seconds which uses hibernate and ends up printing out the same sql statement again and again ... etc.

Is there a way to configure hibernate to print out sql statements but only print each statement once and ignore printing it out in the future?

**update:** It seems there is no way to configure this in hibernate, I ended up using the Spring JDBC for this frequently executing query to avoid the query being printed to the console, every 10 seconds during development. I will keep this question open in case some one figure out an easy way to do it.

Comment: not as far as I know. It simply toggles logging of sql statements - all of them or none of them.

Comment: I wish it would only log statements when it did a prepare statement do other tools like open jpa do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could implement your own `log4net.Appender.IAppender` which uses a set to determine if it already printed it or not

Comment: This is more complex than I a looking for and I am hopping to dump log4j soon in favour of logback and don't want to maintain the code for such an appender.